# seeking help for decoding a call log / PCHR trace files (Call logs)of Huawei V900 R015 machine(.log files)

Tags: telecommunication

I have PCHR trace files of the above mentioned server . But unfortunately I couldn’t find an appropriate decoding software to read those files. I tried manual through a c program but it didn’t work well.
files are of the format `.log` for example

`BSC0007_[PCHR]02Log20150928102948_20150928103252.log`

the header of this HEX files contains this when it decoded to UNICODE

```
.........................
.........................
.........................
.........................
....TT__TOOLMBSC.........
.V900R015....C00SPH588...
..4........Ü_.ß..MBSC CHR
.........................
```

CHR: (Call History Record) Detailed info for the abnormal call.

PCHR: (Performance CHR) Limited info for all calls.

can anyone help me with these

Comment: Welcome to engineering SE. What is the engineering problem you need help? Are you trying to decode the log file.

Comment: thank you. :) yes,
I need to decode It to get the call data. log details.

Comment: http://www.finetopix.com/archive/index.php/t-17450.html

I found this forum. But it doesn't give quitegood information.

and this forum which gives a decoder but they don't allow to download the file.

Comment: Please update your question to explicitly state that your engineering problem seeking help is decoding a call log. You might want to ask the steps to as how call logs are created. Include the above link in the body of the question.

Comment: I have put this question on hold so it can be narrowed down in its scope.

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena yeah.thanks. i did it. any help.:)

Comment: Have you tried the PCHR analyzer tool. Check this link http://www.finetopix.com/showthread.php?27792-PCHR-Analyzer-RAN12-RAN13/page2         Also update the post with all the relevant infomation/research you have on hand. As it is this question will not be opened so others can respond

Comment: @Laksith did you find a way to decode these file? I have same question too